# Unable to set auth_user model primary key as foreign key in my app models.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a blog app with models.py I want to set auth_user model primary key as foreign key to my model in blog app.After adding the appropriate code i am getting the following error?

```
 from django.db import models
 from django.conf import settings

 # Create your models here.
 class Post(models.Model):
   title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   desc=models.TextField()
   date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   author=models.ForeignKey("settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL",
                                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

ERRORS:
blog.Post.author: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'User', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
blog.Post.author: (fields.E307) The field blog.Post.author was declared with a lazy reference to 'blog.user', but app 'blog' doesn't provide model 'user'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* use a *string literal* here, the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) itself is a string that contains the name of the user model, as specified in the documentation:

> **`AUTH_USER_MODEL`**
>
> Default: `'auth.User'`
>
> The **model to use to represent a User**. (..)

You thus implement this like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc=models.TextField()
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The idea is that you either pass a reference to the class itself, or you use the a qualified name as a string for it. But `'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'` is *not* the qualified name of the user model.

Alternatively, you can use [**`get_user_model(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Post(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc=models.TextField()
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    author=models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```